# Rust WASM toolchain not installed, please install it! -- Basilisk node

Tags: rust, macos

I know that similar questions have been asked before but I am not able to resolve this issue with my setup. I am trying to run a basilisk node but keep running into the errors below.

The error log:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `basilisk-runtime v75.0.0 (/Users/james/Documents/projects/Basilisk-node/runtime/basilisk)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/james/Documents/projects/Basilisk-node/target/release/build/basilisk-runtime-70afc7cb3e70cae3/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stderr
  Rust WASM toolchain not installed, please install it!

  Further error information:
  ------------------------------------------------------------
     Compiling wasm-test v1.0.0 (/var/folders/0s/45y2fdk967b8qxthgx6038k00000gn/T/.tmpJBpfH5)
  error[E0463]: can't find crate for `std`
    |
    = note: the `wasm32-unknown-unknown` target may not be installed
    = help: consider downloading the target with `rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown`

  error: requires `sized` lang_item

  For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0463`.
  error: could not compile `wasm-test` due to 2 previous errors
  warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
  error: cannot find macro `println` in this scope
   --> src/main.rs:3:5
    |
  3 |                 println!("{}", env!("RUSTC_VERSION"));
    |                 ^^^^^^^

  error: could not compile `wasm-test` due to 3 previous errors
  ------------------------------------------------------------

make: *** [build] Error 101
```

Current setup:

```
$ rustup show 
Default host: x86_64-apple-darwin rustup home:  /Users/james/.rustup


installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-apple-darwin (default) nightly-2022-02-19-x86_64-apple-darwin nightly-2022-06-19-x86_64-apple-darwin nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin
1.51.0-x86_64-apple-darwin

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

wasm32-unknown-unknown x86_64-apple-darwin

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-2022-06-19-x86_64-apple-darwin (overridden by '/Users/james/Documents/projects/Basilisk-node/rust-toolchain') rustc 1.63.0-nightly (21e9336fe 2022-06-18)
```

What I did step by step:

1. To ensure my installation of rust is clean, I uninstall it with `$ rustup self uninstall`
2. I install substrate and the rust tools via `$ curl https://getsubstrate.io -sSf | bash -s -- --fast` as per the instructions in https://github.com/galacticcouncil/Basilisk-node
3. I run `make build` on the Basilisk node and it complains with the error above. I note that it says `wasm32-unknown-unknown` is not installed so I install it with `rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown`
4. `make build` still errors with the above error

New rustup configuration:

```
$ rustup show

Default host: x86_64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/jamessangalli/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-apple-darwin (default)
nightly-2022-06-19-x86_64-apple-darwin
nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

wasm32-unknown-unknown
x86_64-apple-darwin

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-2022-06-19-x86_64-apple-darwin (overridden by '/Users/jamessangalli/Documents/projects/Basilisk-node/rust-toolchain')
rustc 1.63.0-nightly (21e9336fe 2022-06-18)
```

Comment: Is it possible you have installed rust twice? In any case, the solution is likely to clean up your machine, and re-install rust. Otherwise, please provide more information about how you have set up your computer, and what steps you are following.

Comment: I have reinstalled it but the issue persists. I am able to build substrate on Ubuntu and an m1 mac but not the x86 edition.

Answer (score 3):

The [init script](https://github.com/galacticcouncil/Basilisk-node/blob/00ce0a3cbfc03a2eecdeebd55950b5657ad830f8/scripts/init.sh) specifically mentions to install wasm for the nightly toolchain. So you could try:

```bash
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly
```

Comment: Hi Oliver, I re-followed the steps above and then tried your command, I get back the following and the original error remains: `info: component 'rust-std' for target 'wasm32-unknown-unknown' is up to date`

Answer (score 1):

rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown

try and enter this command worked for me

Answer (score -1):

When I have issues with building Substrate project, my first take is: `rustup update`.

In most cases, the command helps.

Comment: Well this updates your toolchains, it does not add new toolchains or components within them, so in the case you don't yet have the target wasm-unknown-unknown toolchain stuff yet, it won't add it. But one its there it will be included in updates.

Comment: This simply isn't the correct answer to the question asked, no need to feel good or bad for anyone.